# Python - How to correctly save excel file

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, win32com

The following code filters sheets in a workbook. I would like to have the "filtered" workbook saved (i.e., with filtered sheets). Anyone knows what am I missing/doing wrong?

When I open the workbook I still see all the original sheets, when I only expect "Sheet1" and "Cacaca".

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import win32com
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:/Prueba/GOOG.xlsm")
print("All Sheets:",[wb.Sheets(i+1).Name for i in range(wb.Sheets.Count)]) # Prints ['Cacaca', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet1', 'Perro']

def included(sheet_name):
    l = ['Sheet1', 'Cacaca']
    if sheet_name in l:
        return True

wb.__Sheets__ = filter(included, [wb.Sheets(i+1).Name for i in range(wb.Sheets.Count)])

print(list(wb.__Sheets__)) # Prints ['Cacaca', 'Sheet1']

wb.Save()
wb.Close()
excel.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
f=open('excel.csv','w')
file=csv.reader(f)
file.writerow(['Sheet1', 'Cacaca'])
data=[]
while True:
     a=input('Sheet1 :')
     b=input('cacaca :')
     rec=[a,b]
     data.append(rec)
     ans=input('Add more ? (y/n) =')
     if ans.lower()=='n':
              break
file.writerows(data)
file.close()
```

To save an excel file in python, you can make use of the csv module which is in built in python. Make sure you import the module first.

Comment: Oh okay. Got the output ?